# What is the correct year to use in the reference list?

Tags: citations

I am wondering what would be the correct year to use for this book?:

http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/9195

On the page it says 2014, and on google scholar I see that other people have used 2014. But inside the book as can be seen here

[link,](https://books.google.no/books?id=7hS3CgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=asymptotic%20methods%20for%20integrals&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=asymptotic%20methods%20for%20integrals&f=false)

it says copyright 2015. What year should I put for it?

Comment: Use the one which will not create any problem during the citation. In this context, I will use 2014 as the year.

Answer (score 2):

You can find this in books which are published at the end of a year. For instance, if books are published in November or December, publisher will state this year as publication year in their online catalogue. But the publisher has also assigned such a published book for the following year, because it will be mainly promoted and distributed to libraries, book stores etc in the next year. 
 Here is another example of 2 different years of publication of a book: [publisher website states 2016](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/austerity-and-recovery-in-ireland-9780198792376?cc=gb&lang=en&#) and [google books shows in the book 2017](https://books.google.ie/books?id=HQ6DDQAAQBAJ&pg=PR3&hl=de&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=2#v=onepage&q&f=false) 
 In case you have read the book and not the few pages on google books, I would say the year in the book is more reliable and would cite it as 2015.